# Rails - Traversing a json hashes and arrays with HTTParty

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

So I've got the below business happening, which works... but even as a rookie, I'm thinking it looks pretty horrid.

The structure is that:
"Each product has an array of artists. Only return the products with the correct artist"

```
def fetch_products(artist)
  result = get("/#{@id}/products.js", :headers => {'Accept' => 'application/json'})
  products = []

  result.each do |product| 
    if not product['artists'].find_all {|i| i['name'].downcase == artist.downcase }.empty?
      products << product
    end
  end
  products
end
```

If anyone's got any tips I'd love get some better understanding on a 'better' and/or 'faster' way to do this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is not too bad as it is. However, you can skip the `result.each` loop and just use `find_all` directly to get all the instances you are looking for without looping.

A simple example:

```
x={ :a => ['a','b'] , :b => ['c','d'], :c=>['b','e']}

x.find_all { |k,v| !v.grep(/^A$/i).empty? }
```

Returns:

```
 [[:a, ["a", "b"]]]
```

The `grep` method searches `v` (the hash value - an array) for any entry matching a certain regular expression.

If you prefer not to use `grep` you can implement your logic directly:

```
x.find_all {|k,v| v.any? { |m| m.downcase == "a" } }
```

Comment: That's great! The second example is so clear and should wok great. Thanks for the heads up. I was struggling how to put blocks within blocks properly, but this makes it obvious.